# How to get the related_name for a foreign key?

Tags: python, django

In django I can define a foreign key like so:

```
class MyModel(model)
    foo = models.ForeignKey(foo,related_name="bar")
```

Given a field name on a model, how can I get the `related_name` (*not the related field*) for that field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the class:

```
MyModel._meta.get_field('foo').related_query_name()
```

If you have an instance:

```
model._meta.get_field('foo').related_query_name()
```

Comment: I'm giving this the tick because its much cleaner than my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

It can be gotten like so:

```
> getattr(MyModel,'foo').field.rel.get_accessor_name()
'bar'
```